# How to add the result of a sql query to an existing datareader

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a list of `TaskIDs` that are associated with different `Users`. This is a separate table named `Assignments`. There is a second table for each of the `Tasks` with different information. if i want to show a user all their tasks i can get all the `TaskID` that they signed up for like this

```
sqlcommand sqlcom=new sqlcommand("select AssignedTaskId in Assignments where Assigneduserid=userid")
```

I can get a list of all their tasks. now i want to run a sql for each task from the last query to get the task information. how can i have a data reader that i can add to and loop through each `AssignedTaskID` and run a sql query and add the info to that data reader?
finally i will use that data reader to read data and show them results

Comment: What is the *actual* problem? A DataReader is a *reader*, meant to retrieve the results of a single query. It doesn't store any information, you can't add anything to it. Why do you wan to add anything to it? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: im aware that i can loop through each one of them and read the data. i was hoping i could have one data reader that i save data into throughout the method and and the end read all thats been saved into that dataread

Comment: I repeat, a DataReader is a reader. Nothing is saved into it, so even asking about adding or saving things to it makes no sense. It's only used to read the results of a single DbCommand *execution*, so trying to reuse it makes no sense either. That's a very important feature too, not a limitation. Post your actual code and explain the *real problem* you want to solve

Comment: If you want to combine data from multiple queries, you *have* to use multiple commands to begin with, or one command with a UNION clause to combine multiple queries in SQL. A DataReader is created when a  DbCommand is executed, so even if you execute a command twice you'll get two different readers.

Comment: If you want to combine two tables to return data, the easiest and fastest way is to use JOIN in the SQL query

Answer (score 0):

Create a list to stored the ID's in.

```
List<int> assignedTaskIDs = new List<int>

 if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            assignedTaskIDs.Add(reader.GetInt32(0))
              
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
```

Then loop through the list using a foreach loop.

```
foreach (var id in assignedTaskIDs)
 {
    //Execute sql query using the id variable
 }
```